# Creating OrderedDict from list does not retain order

Tags: python, python-2.7

If:

```
for k in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']: print k
a
b
c
d
```

Then why when creating a ordered dictionary order is different:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

OrderedDict({k: k for k in ['a','b','c','d']})
OrderedDict([('a', 'a'), ('c', 'c'), ('b', 'b'), ('d', 'd')])
```

Comment: To summarize that link: once you use `{k: k for k in ['a','b','c','d']}` (a `dict` comprehension), you lose order

Comment: Thanks @BradSolomon, it is obvious now when you pointed it out.